# Detecting environment variables in Ruby on Travis CI

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I have a set of dotfiles that I am trying to test on Travis CI.

There are certain elements of the dotfiles that I don't want wish to test on Travis (like installing Homebrew apps). To detect if I'm in Travis I'm using the following:

```
if defined?($TRAVIS) && $TRAVIS != ''
  $TEST_ENV = true
else
  $TEST_ENV = false
end

print "TEST ENV: " + $TEST_ENV.to_s
```

where I detect the Travis environment variable and then echo out the result in the console.

However, I keep getting `$TEST_ENV` as `false` and cannot work out why.

Answer (score 2):

`$TRAVIS` is not an environment variable, it's a global variable. Environment variable looks like this:

```
ENV['TRAVIS']
```

Comment: So how do I get the code in my question to function as intended?

Comment: @BarryBlade: ah, I see. Should as simple as `if ENV['TRAVIS']`

Comment: You'd think that would work. Alas it's not detecting it. Even when I add the variable manually.

Comment: `print "TEST ENV: " + $TEST_ENV.to_s + "\n"
print "TRAVIS: " + ENV['TRAVIS'].to_s + "\n"`
gives
`TEST ENV: false
TRAVIS: `

Comment: @BarryBlade: it's unreadable. Put it into a gist or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146940/discussion-between-barry-blade-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 1):

### In Your Code, *$TRAVIS* is Always Undefined

There are a number of issues with your code. These include:

1. *$TRAVIS* is a Ruby global, not an environment variable.
2. The environment is never checked because you aren't calling [ENV::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ENV.html#method-c-5B-5D).
3. In some cases, `&&` may bind too tightly. The difference between `&&` and `and` is largely in precedence, so you should use parentheses to separate multiple conditions unless you are sure of what the parser will see.
4. In your current code, `defined? $TRAVIS` will always be false.

To test an environment variable, you could simply check the stringified value like so:

```
# Are you sure you need a global variable here? If not, remove the dollar sign.
$test_env = ENV['TRAVIS'].to_s.empty?
```

Note that an unset environment variable will be nil, so you'll want to call #to_s before #empty? if an unset variable and an empty string are logically equivalent for your use case. Otherwise, you'll want to explicitly handle nil.